# Unable to compile move

Tags: aptos

I have been following https://aptos.dev/move/move-on-aptos/cli/#profiling-gas-usage and tried to run

> aptos move compile --package-dir
> aptos-move/move-examples/hello_blockchain/ --named-addresses
> hello_blockchain=superuser

I got the following:

> error: invalid value 'hello_blockchain=superuser' for
> '--named-addresses <NAMED_ADDRESSES>': Invalid arguments: Profile
> superuser not found

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

`superuser` in `named-addresses hello_blockchain=superuser` should be an actual address like `0x123456`, you can create a new address by `aptos init`.